# Is there a way to translate bindings with Angular native internationalization mechanisms?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

### Problem

I'm implementing translations for my Angular 6 application. It needs to support static texts of the app in multiple languages. I don't need dynamic translations during runtime - I just need producing an app with texts in a language chosen during build.

Angular has the whole [page on internationalization](https://angular.io/guide/i18n), but it focuses solely on situations where all the texts are hard coded in the templates, like in the code below:

```
<p>This is a hard coded text</p>
```

That's hardly a situation in my template. Additionally it seems to me impossible or extremely dirty to write the whole application with all the texts hard-coded in templates, so if that's the only mechanism available for translation, then it seems completely useless to me.

In my components I very often have texts bound to some JavaScript variables (or to be precise object properties), like in the code below:

```
<li *ngFor="let navigationEntry of navigationEntries">
  <a [href]="navigationEntry.url">
    {{ navigationEntry.text }}
  </a>
</li>
```

Let's say the variable is still static, just being stored in the component or a service, e.g.:

```
navigationEntries: Array = [
  {
    url: "/",
    text: "Home",
  },
  {
    url: "/login",
    text: "Login",
  },
  {
    url: "/admin",
    text: "Admin panel",
  },
];
```

### Question

Is there a way to use Angular native translation (internationalization) mechanisms to translate the anchor texts (or actually the `text` properties of the `navigationEntries` members) during build time? The structure of the JavaScript data and the HTML of the template can change.

If Angular native internationalization mechanisms can't handle that (but then I wonder what's their use at all), then what are other solutions that could help with implementing such translations? I found [ngx-translate](http://www.ngx-translate.com/) library, but it's providing translations which can be dynamically changed at runtime and ideally I wouldn't like to add that unnecessary overhead of dynamic solution watching on all the translated texts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Angular native translation mechanim to do this. We use the following pattern a lot to get around the missing dynamic translations in angular i18n:

You have an array of messages, and then use it with ngFor and ngSwitch to template the messages, something like this for your example:

```
<li *ngFor="let navigationEntry of navigationEntries">
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="navigationEntry.text">
    <a [href]="navigationEntry.url" *ngSwitchCase="'Home'" i18n="@@home">
      Home
    </a>
    <a [href]="navigationEntry.url" *ngSwitchCase="'Login'" i18n="@@login">
      Login
    </a>
    <a [href]="navigationEntry.url" *ngSwitchCase="'Admin panel'" i18n="@@adminPanel">
      Admin panel
    </a>
  <ng-container>
</li>
```

It's somewhat verboose - but it works for a surprising amount of use cases.

Note, the i18n id (the string following the `@@`) is just an unique id, which is used in the xlf translation file. The string can be anything, I use the message itself, if possible, for readability and reuse.

Comment: What I don't like about that method is the verbosity you mentioned, which breaks DRY - I have to repeat the same structure multiple times. But it seems to work and answers my question, so thanks.